# python discord bot embeds

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

From this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pyj2.png) im trying to make it so the second line does not have a title and can just sit right under the first one.
Here is my code :

````
  embed.add_field(name="hello", value="```hi```", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="undefined", value="```hi```", inline=True)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: The embed in the image has the title "Test". If you don't want "undefined" to be visible, it is not possible. Embed fields need to have both the name and the value. What you could do is, take the value of the second field and append it to the value of the first one with a `\n`.

Comment: No, as mentioned by Sandy it's not possible to have an empty `name` for an embed field. You should just add a few newlines and put the two value fields together.

Comment: You could try putting just a space instead of text.